Continuity of the induced map of fixed points of a product map: Banach Contraction Principle
Let $X$ be a complete metric space, $Y$ a topological space. $f:X\times Y\to X$ a continuous map such that each $f_y:X\to X$ mapping $x\mapsto f(x,y)$ is a contraction, that is, there exists a $0<\lambda_y<1$ such that $d(f(x_1, y), f(x_2, y))\le \lambda_yd(x_1, x_2)$.
By the Banach contraction principle, each $f_y$ has a unique fixed point, call it $\phi(y)$. This induces a map $Y\xrightarrow{\phi}X$. Could someone give an example satisfying the above, but such that the map $\phi$ is not continuous?
Context Assuming that the $f_y$ are contractions uniformly in $y$, that is, there is some $\lambda$ such that $\lambda_y=\lambda$ works for all $y$, enables one to prove that such a $\phi$ must be continuous. The question is to demonstrate that this hypothesis is necessary.

Let $X:=c_0(\mathbb{N})$ be endowed with the maximum norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ and let $Y:=\{1/n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}\cup \{0\}$ be endowed with the metric $d(y_1,y_2)=|y_1-y_2|$. The function $f:X\times Y \to X$, defined as
$$
f(x,y)=f((x_k),y)= \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
(0, \dots,0, (1-1/n)x_n+1/n,0,0,\dots), & y=1/n\\
(0,0,0,\dots), & y=0 
\end{array} \right.
$$
is continuous: Let $(x^{(j)})$ and $(y^{(j)})$ be convergent sequences in $X$ and $Y$, respectively with limits $u\in X$ and $v\in Y$, say.  If $v \not=0$ then $(y^{(j)})$ is eventually constant and $f(x^{(j)},y^{(j)}) \to f(u,v)$ $(j \to \infty)$ is clear. If $v=0$  (ignoring the case that some $y^{(j)}=0$; these can be removed)
$$
f(x^{(j)},y^{(j)})=(0, \dots,0, (1-1/{n_j})x^{(j)}_{n_j}+1/n_j,0,0,\dots)
$$
with $y^{(j)}=1/n_j \to 0$, that is $n_j \to \infty$. Now
$$
|x^{(j)}_{n_j} -u_{n_j}| \le \|x^{(j)} -u\|_\infty \to 0 \quad (j \to \infty),
$$
and since $u_{n_j} \to 0$ also $x^{(j)}_{n_j} \to 0$ $(j \to \infty)$. Hence
$$
\|f(x^{(j)},y^{(j)})\|_\infty \le  (1-1/{n_j})|x^{(j)}_{n_j}|+1/n_j \to 0,
$$
which means $f(x^{(j)},y^{(j)}) \to (0,0,0,\dots) = f(u,0)$.
For each $y \in Y$ the function $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ is a contraction with constant $<1$ and the unique fixed point is
$$
\phi(y)= \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
(0, \dots,0, 1_n,0,0,\dots), & y=1/n\\
(0,0,0,\dots), & y=0 
\end{array} \right..
$$
So $\|\phi(1/n)-\phi(0)\|_\infty =1$ $(n \in \mathbb{N})$ and $\phi$ is not continuous at $0$.
I hope everything is correct. Please check.
